# Django - Authentication not functioning in when deployed

Tags: python, django

I am unable to log in after deploying my Django application, but can when using the inbuilt dev server. I'll put the error and what im using below. I have migrated to the live sql server with no errors. I created a superuser with no errors. the only real change to the django files was getting static files set up which shouldnt impact the db (where im assuming this error is coming from). Here is the error:

> TypeError at /login/ argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable 
> Request Method:   POST Request URL:   http://sitename/login/ 
>  Django
> Version:  3.0  Exception Type:    TypeError Exception Value:   argument of
> type 'NoneType' is not iterable  
>  Exception
> Location: c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py in
> encode_value, line 59 
>  Python Executable:    c:\python39\python.exe Python 
> Version:  3.9.4

Now a few core notes about whats running in the environment and how its deployed:

deployed on windows IIS  
utilizing mssql with django_mssql_backend-2.8.1 (ive verified all packages are on the same version. I think the only difference is python on 3.9.1 in dev vs 3.9.4 in prod)  
Django 3.0
SQL Server is on 2019 in dev vs 2017 in prod. not sure if that changes anything or i need to change any settings due to this but the inital migrate commands and create user commands worked.
pyodbc-4.0.30 
wfastcgi-3.0.0(prod only) 
using django.contrib.auth (authenticate, login, logout) for authentication. again, all working in dev environment.

does anyone have any ideas as to why this isnt functioning the same in production as when running in the dev environment? In fact, it runs fine (can log in/out) when running manage.py runserver, but not when accessing through IIS.

Edit: the login view is below, done mostly following a youtube tutorial and full error traceback below that:

```
def loginpage(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('alfred-home')
else:
    if request.method== 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('alfred-home')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or password is incorrect')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'authentication/login.html', context)
```

error message:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://lsdmalfred/login/?next=/

Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.9.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'home.apps.HomeConfig',
 'authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
 'automation.apps.AutomationConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\inetpub\alfred\alfred\authentication\views.py", line 30, in loginpage
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 72, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 46, in authenticate
    user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 44, in get_by_natural_key
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: username})
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1124, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\compiler.py", line 177, in as_sql
    supports_offset_clause = self.connection.sql_server_version >= 2012
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 400, in sql_server_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "c:\python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 604, in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 218, in _cursor
    conn = super()._cursor()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 236, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 293, in get_new_connection
    connstr = encode_connection_string(cstr_parts)
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 49, in encode_connection_string
    return ';'.join(
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
    '%s=%s' % (k, encode_value(v))
  File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 59, in encode_value
    if ';' in v or v.strip(' ').startswith('{'):

Exception Type: TypeError at /login/
Exception Value: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'removeddbname',
    'USER': 'removedusername',
    'PASSWORD': removedpassword,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
    },
},
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the _full_ error traceback. Also show your login view unless you use the builtin one.

Comment: Can you share login view

Comment: @lsdmctrubey looks like you have some problem in your connection settings? Please show your database settings (Remove any sensitive details like password, etc.)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat added

Comment: OK. identified a problem. for some reason it was able to perform the migrations and create its authentication tables setup as is, but would not let me log in. however, if i changed the password to a normal string i could log in. im not sure why it is able to create its tables but not log in set up as it was. ive had similar issues with storing the secret key as an environment variable that i havent worked out yet.

Comment: @lsdmctrubey "changed the password to a normal string" how were you setting it before?